# How to repeatedly stop a program after x minutes and re run it changing one variable in python?

Tags: python, timer, cron, cron-task

I have a program written in python which goes as follows:

```
for i in range(4954):
    ........
    save("/Downloads/pos_" + str(i) + ".h5")
```

The fact is the program running time increases exponentially(we observed it using `time.time()`)

So what I need is run the program for 10 min and then re run the program.
But I just need to change the i in for loop to the number at which it is stopped.
I can do a cron job, but what should I do to change `i` value?

Comment: What stops the program after x minutes?

Answer (score 1):

You could use `marshal.dump`(https://docs.python.org/3/library/marshal.html) to save the value when stopping the program, and then loading it via `marshal.load` when starting.

Honestly, I think it would be a much better approach to fix the root cause of the problem, i.e. solving the exponential run time.

Answer (score 1):

If each iteration (each `i` value) in the loop is independent with each other, you can parallelize it with [`ProcessPoolExecutor`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#processpoolexecutor-example):

```py
import concurrent.futures

def downloader(i):
    ...
    save("/Downloads/pos_" + str(i) + ".h5")

def main():
    i_range = list(range(4954))
    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(10) as executor: # create 10 workers (subprocesses)
        for number, result in zip(i_range , executor.map(downloader, i_range)):
            print('File %d is scheduled to download!' % (number))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

This requires Python3.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using a generator:

```
import time

def gen(n):
    for i in range(n):
        yield n

g = gen(4954)

time_limit = 600

while some_condition:
# whatever condition required for you to continually restart this section

    start = time.time()
    while time.time() - start < time_limit:
        ... some code...
        try: 
            save("/Downloads/pos_" + str(next(g)) + ".h5")
        except StopIteration:
            print('end of iterations')
```

Where `g` will remember the iteration it's on and continue the next time you call `next(g)`.

Comment: Its better to assign `i=next(g)` and use `i` later because every invocation to `next` will increase the counter by 1. And make sure `next(g)` is placed inside the `try` structure.

Comment: In this instance I don't imagine there's any difference between `i=next(g)` vs just calling `next(g)` directly.  The last `i` would be released regardless and are incremented correctly.

Comment: I assume this program is used to download something from Internet. So `i` should be also used to construct the URL.

Comment: Another problem: the generator object `g` should be saved in a file to survive restarts.

Comment: Right, but I still don't see your point.  If the generator was a bit more complex and the yield might be affected, I might agree.  In this case i fail to see how it is any different.  Also, this script assumes everything is done *within* the script itself.  It does not attempt to be a solution that relies on external restart.

Comment: The PO said: "I can do a cron job ..."

Comment: That's just one solution though, the OP didn't say they *must* do a cron job.  If you can get away without an external dependency, why not do it all within the script? I guess the *real* question is, *why* is the processing time increasing exponentially in OP's script? That might eliminate the need to restart every 10 minutes altogether, but that part of details is not clear.

Comment: She/He also said "So what I need is run the program for 10 min and then *re run* the program." We have different understanding about how to "re run", by an external program like `cron` or within the python process. The PO should clarify that.

Answer (score 0):

Here my solution:

```
import os
import time
import threading

class test_class(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.iter_number = 0
        self.new_iter_number = 0

        self.iter_file_dir = "/tmp_file.txt" # tmp file where sto the new iteration number remaining

        self.end_iteration = False # Flag to stop the iteration

        self.delay = 1 # Seconds that means 10 minutes

        with open(self.iter_file_dir, "r") as file:
            self.iter_number = int(file.readline())

        self.run()

    def for_function(self):
        for i in range(self.iter_number):
            save("/Downloads/pos_" + str(i) + ".h5")
            if(self.end_iteration):
                self.new_iter_number = self.iter_number - i
                break

    def run(self):
        threading.Thread(name="Iteration_Thread", target=self.for_function).start()

        time_remaining = self.delay-time.time()%self.delay
        time.sleep(time_remaining)

        self.end_iteration = True

        # Save the file with the new value
        with open(self.iter_file_dir, 'w') as f:
            f.write(str(self.new_iter_number))
test_class()
```

The idea behind this code is simple:

1. Create a tmp_file.txt where you want, and write in them the number of iteration that you need in the for.
2. Create a timer that sleep for X minutes and after that set a flag that terminate the for loop.
3. After that save in the tmp_file.txt the new calculated iteration number

Each time that the cron run the program it will load the new iteration value. Obviously when the iteration are finished in the file the 0 is written, so no more iteration were performed.